# Estimating repeatability using posterior.mode() & MCMCglmm

Tags: mcmc

I have been trying to estimate repeatability for six behavioural variables following Dingemanse & Dochtermann (2013), specifically the first example in their supporting text. The posterior.mode function is supposed to give me the repeatability estimate, while the HPDinterval function gives a 95% confidence(credibility?) interval. 
However, when I run their script on my own data set I get negative repeatability estimates for half of my behavioural variables. Their data set has five measures per individual while mine only has two. I created some variations of their data set to test what may be the problem:

1. Kept all five measures per individual but made the measures quite dissimilar (i.e., low repeatability)
2. Reduced the number of measures per individual from five to three where I kept the three most similar measures from the original (high repeatability)
3. Reduced the number of measures per individual from five to three where I kept the three most disimilar measures from the original (low repeatability),
4. Reduced the number of measures per individual from three to two where I kept the two most similar measures from the original (high repeatability)
5. Reduced the number of measures per individual from three to two where I kept the two most disimilar measures from the original (low repeatability).

I ran their script on all these and got:

1. The posterior.mode function produced a negative repeatability
2. The posterior.mode function produced a repeatability of 0.85
3. The posterior.mode function produced a negative repeatability
4. The posterior.mode function produced a repeatability of 0.98
5. The posterior.mode function produced a negative repeatability

To me this signals that this method does not handle very low repeatability. However, we have discussed it with some researchers at the university and they argue that getting a negative repeatability estimate this way is impossible. Has anyone else run into this problem? Or do anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
rep1 <- MCMCglmm(log.exp3A ~ factor(order),random=~bird.id, family="gaussian", data=repeat.sub, verbose=FALSE)
rep.1<-(rep1$VCV[,"bird.id"]/ (rep1$VCV[,"bird.id"]+rep1$VCV[,"units"]))
posterior.mode(rep.1)
HPDinterval(rep.1)
```